# Selecting row count from associated table without subselect

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, subquery

I'm trying to write a SQL query that returns a single row for each user. That row must contain a count of the schools assigned to that user and a sum of the points across all schools assigned to that user.

Tables:

```
users (id, email)
schools (id, user_id, points (int))
```

Relation `users` to `schools` is one-to-many.

I've gotten this far:

```
select u.id, u.email, 
  count(*) as total_schools, 
  sum(points) as total_points
from users u
left join schools s 
  on u.id = s.user_id 
group by u.id
```

But this doesn't quite work. The `count(*) as total_school` is wrong. It returns the number of user rows, not the number of assigned school rows.

How do I get that count?

Comment: Check your results again. It should return the number of assigned school, except for the case when a user has no schools assigned. Change the `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(s.user_id)` or to `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)` if a user can be assigned to a school more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the schools table is the id/user-id pair unique? If not that is why you maybe be returned the number of times the user appears for a school.

Try using distinct instead of count(*). Although be aware that nulls will be omitted where they are not for count(*).

```
select u.id, u.email, 
   count(distinct(s.id)) as total_schools, 
   sum(points) as total_points
from users u
left join schools s 
   on u.id = s.user_id 
group by u.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eb4b/1/0)